# How to display the next data of the database using C#?

Tags: c#

Displaying a data from a database (MS Access) and I want at the end of the data selected it will display another form. I tried using if loop

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //**This will select the next row**
{
    currentRow++;
    nextRow();
}

private void nextRow()
{
    if (currentRow <= n)
    {   //**Randomize the RadioButtons.Text**
        var row = dTable.Rows[currentRow];
        List<string> list = new List<string> { row["C1"].ToString(), row["C2"].ToString(), row["C3"].ToString(), row["C4"].ToString() };
        lblQuest.Text = row["QUESTION"].ToString();
        btn1.Text = row["C1"].ToString();
        btn2.Text = row["C2"].ToString();
        btn3.Text = row["C3"].ToString();
        btn4.Text = row["C4"].ToString();
        var ans = row["ANSWER"].ToString();
        var rbtn = new[] { btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4 };
        var rnd = new Random();
        var shuffTxt = list.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next(list.Count)).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < rbtn.Length; i++)
        {
            rbtn[i].Text = shuffTxt[i];
        }
    }
    if (currentRow > n)
    {   //**If the currentRow is already greater than the n selected rows, it will display a form**
        frmPIPE frm = new frmPIPE();
        frm.Show();
        Hide();
    }
}
```

But when `currentRow > n`; It displays an error

> "There is no row at position n"

Comment: You mean that `frmPIPE frm = new frmPIPE();` this line raises that error?! ;).

Comment: even without that code. when the currentRow is greater than the number of rows it gives an error.

Comment: at var row = dTable.Rows[currentRow];

Comment: Smells like a standard off-by-1 bug.  C# starts count at 0, not 1.

Comment: So, it is not when `currentRow > n` it is may be at `currentRow = n`;  just call `currentRow++;` after `nextRow();` ;).

Comment: still having the error

Comment: @shA.t, what i have observed when changing the callout. the first data will display twice when i press my next button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering if this is to do with 0-based indexing, and you need to alter your code to:

```
if (currentRow < n)
...
else if (currentRow >= n)
```

Comment: this solves my problem. thanks. but why >= condition works when i only need it to be greater than? this puzzled me.

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with the entirety of your code, but with 0-based indexing, say you have a set of some sort, [23, 34, 45], if you ask for the value at position/index 2, you'll get 45, and if you ask for the value at position/index 3, you'll get an error message similar to the one you posted. So it's 0-based, meaning if you ask for the value at position/index 0, you'll get 23 (the first value). Similarly, if you have a result set/table with 50 rows, they will be indexed as 0-49, so asking for the row at index 50 will throw an exception.

Comment: I've also amended my code to say `else if` instead of `if` for the second statement. This means that the second condition won't be checked if the first one was true, which won't affect this code, as the two conditions are mutually exclusive.